# Flutter - Install on IOS emulator open the app and immediately close

Tags: iphone, debugging, flutter

I am trying to run Flutter sample default app on an IOS emulator. The app installs on the emulator and then open with a white screen and then immediately closes. I don't see any error log or fail error. Flutter doctor output shows not issues.

Comment: I figure out the issue. I had to sign my application in xCode.

Comment: Following the flutter documentation on using the simulator the signing process doesn't seem to be necessary. How did you sign your application @Edmand Looi

Comment: I opened Xcode and made build there. Xcode showed me error